# Can anyone suggest the Azure AD sign-in/ Sign-Out code flow for the Asp.net core Web API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Can anyone suggest the Azure AD sign-in/ Sign-Out code flow for the Asp.net core Web API.

I am developing the  Web API project(same as https://app.hubspot.com/crm-settings-email/6849578/email/connectedEmails) for Office 365 integration and  have implemented all the required MS GRAPH API but stuck with the Sign-In/Sign-out process for the Personal Microsoft account holder. tried the sample code for OpenId-Connect V2 code flow but not able to return any Access Token or Code in return.

Can anyone suggest the correct code-flow for Web-API project and the how to register or sign-in/out the any Microsoft User into my Azure APP?

Comment: So you are facing problem only with personal Microsoft accounts?Your app need to register as multi tenant app which can handle personal account

Comment: @Hari Krishna, I have registered the multi-tenant app only and tried the sample code but not getting the token in response for Azure as well as Personal account holders. Also can you recommend what code flow should i use into my .net core Web-API project for this functionality

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) is good for your requirement as you have mentioned  .net core Web-API project. Please go through [Ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) for different implementations of other authentication flows (which can be implemented MSAL library) which helps you to choose your own code flow based on your scenario.

Please go through [sample given by Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC) which helps you in handling AAD login with personal accounts. Also, Please make sure you have selected ***Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts*** option while creating an app in [app registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app).

Comment: Yes Hari Krishna, I have selected Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts option while creating an app.  Thank you for the suggestion, Will go through the documentation.